# How do I convert NSData back to NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdata, binary-data

So first I have this code to convert the NSArray into NSData:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];

NSData* encodedArray = [NSData dataWithBytes:myArray length:1];
```

Now I want to convert it back to an NSArray but I don't know how to do it.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
NSArray *receivedArray = [encodedArray bytes];
```

But it chrashes.

Comment: Side note - you can create that array using newer syntax: `NSArray *myArray = @[ @3 ];`.

Comment: Thank you this will make everything much easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];

...

NSArray *arrayCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

See the [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html) on the subject.

Comment: Someone told me not to use archived data because it uses a big bandwidth.

Comment: @Arbitur It's your only choice I'm afraid.

Comment: @Arbitur Another option would be serialize the array to JSON but that requires that the array only contains certain types of objects. If you have custom objects then archiving is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
NSArray *array=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedArray]
```

Comment: This won't work since the OP's code is only storing a single byte. There is nothing to unarchive.